# Set iframe parameter "allow-modals" for Google Sites?

Tags: google-chrome, security, iframe, google-apps-script, google-sites

My Google Scripts using print() or alert() methods not working anymore due to the latest Google Sites update, here an error message provided by Google Chrome for a Google Script integrated as a iframe into a Google Sites webpage:

```
Ignored call to 'alert()'. The document is sandboxed, and the 'allow-modals' keyword is not set.
```

Do we have a solution to solve this problem?

Comment: `integrated as a iframe` Integrate it with custom html with no sandbox?

Comment: @TheMaster My script is included into a Google Sites webpage, and new versions of Google Sites does not allow to set custom HTML.

Comment: Actually it does. In embed code, you can just enter html directly.